# A list of visited questions or the total list of questions as they appeared

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to get a list of visited questions (by me) or the list of all questions as they appeared (arrived at) TeX SX?

Comment: I guess you will be suggested to use browser history.

Comment: Does `Questions -> newest` do the trick? (listing questions in the order they were posted)

Comment: In addition to Count Zero’s reply take a look at my answer here: [RSS feed for New questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/rss-feed-for-new-questions/2410#2410).

Comment: I guess, the short answer is No. :)  @Speravir:  I do not follow the intent of the question (or your answer to it).  However, I will read it carefully later.